# Sails disable criteria for REST in GET

Tags: rest, sails.js

I have implemented passport-local strategy and passport-bearer strategy.

When user logins with username/password credentials, I generate JSON Web Token which returns to requester. On each request I get `access_token` from query, decode this token from JWT to object and make bearer authorization implemented in `/api/policies`. And all auth works fine.

But when I provide this `access_token` to RESTful route i.e. `user` I got empty array.

The problem, that Sails accepts `access_token` as criteria.

Example:

`GET /user ## Forbidden
GET /user?access_token=<token> ## Empty array`

How can I disable or fix it?

Comment: Can we see your controller code that ````GET /user```` maps to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably be better off sending your access token in a header than in the URL.  But if what your asking is how to blacklist a certain property from being used as criteria in a blueprint route, it can be done in the following way in your **config/routes.js** file:

```
"GET /user": {blueprint: "find", criteria: {blacklist: ["access_token"]}}
```

This will override the default blacklist, so you may want to include those defaults in your custom array:

```
"GET /user": {
  blueprint: "find", 
  criteria: {
      blacklist: ["access_token", "limit", "skip", "sort", "populate"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. I don't think about headers, seems that this can resolve problem.
And returns to second question. So what if I want to set blacklist property to all routes? I need set all routes like above, or can somehow do it in other way in single line of code?

Comment: You could set `req.options.criteria.blacklist` in a [policy](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies) and apply it to all controller actions...